# Strange UI Freeze ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, telerik

So I am going to do my best to explain what is happening. When ever I run my asp.net web app, a request is made to "GetRouteData". For some reason, after the data has already arrived, my UI will freeze for a good 20 seconds.

**The weird part:**

So now if I go ahead and put a break point on the controller method "GetRouteData" it stops I hit continue and no UI freeze? Everything is smooth. It always goes smooth if I put a break point and hit continue but freezes if I just let it run like normal?

**My Controller Action:**

```
public JsonResult GetRouteData([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
{
    return Json(_routeManagementService.GetMaterialRouteData().Select(x => new RouteDataViewModel {
        Id = x.Id,
        MaterialNumber = x.MaterialNumber,
        BoxSize = x.BoxSize,
        EnclosureIntegration = x.EnclosureIntegration,
        EnclosurePreparation = x.EnclosurePreparation,
        FinalWiring = x.FinalWiring,
        Kiesling = x.Kiesling ?? null,
        Packaging = x.Packaging,
        PanelAssembly = x.PanelAssembly,
        PanelWiring = x.PanelWiring,
        Test = x.Test,
        ProductionLineId = x.ProductionLineId,
        BoxSizeId = x.BoxSizeId
    }).OrderBy(x => PadNumbers(x.MaterialNumber)).ToDataSourceResult(request),JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}


public static string PadNumbers(string input)
{
    return Regex.Replace(input, "[0-9]+", match => match.Value.PadLeft(10, '0'));
}
```

**My View:**

```
@(Html.Kendo()
.Grid<RouteConfigurator.Core.ViewModels.RouteDataViewModel>()
.Name("RouteDataGrid")
.Columns(column =>
{
    column.Bound(x => x.Id).Width("150px");
    column.Bound(x => x.MaterialNumber).Width("150px");
    column.ForeignKey(x => x.ProductionLineId, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["productionLines"], "Id", "Name").Width("125px");
    column.ForeignKey(x => x.BoxSizeId, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["boxSizes"], "Id", "Size").Width("100px");
    column.Bound(x => x.PanelAssembly).Width("175px");
    column.Bound(x => x.PanelWiring).Width("175px");
    column.Bound(x => x.EnclosurePreparation).Width("175px");
    column.Bound(x => x.EnclosureIntegration).Width("175px");
    column.Bound(x => x.FinalWiring).Width("175px");
    column.Bound(x => x.Test).Width("175px");
    column.Bound(x => x.Packaging).Width("175px");
    column.Bound(x => x.Kiesling).Width("175px");
    column.Template(@<text> </text>).Title("");
})
.Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
.ToolBar(toolbar =>
{
    toolbar.Create();
    toolbar.Save();
    toolbar.Excel();
})
.Excel(excel => excel.FileName("RouteData.xlsx").AllPages(true))
.Groupable()
.Sortable(x => x.Enabled(true).SortMode(GridSortMode.MultipleColumn))
.Filterable()
.HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 500px" })
.Scrollable(x => x.Virtual(true))
.DataSource(ds =>
{
    ds.Ajax()
        .ServerOperation(true)
        .Model(model =>
        {
            model.Id(x => x.Id);
        })
        .Sort(sort => { sort.Add("MaterialNumber").Ascending(); })
        .Events(events => events.Error("error"))
        .Update(update => update.Action("EditRouteData", "Route"))
        .Create(create => create.Action("CreateRouteData", "Route"))
        .Read(read => read.Action("GetRouteData", "Route"));

}))
```

I believe it has something to do with the web socket taking 22 seconds. I really am not sure what to look for in this case? Can someone point me in the right direction?

[image: Network Record]

Thank you!

Comment: The issue could be with Visual Studio. Try cleaning the solution then deleting `obj` folder then rebuild it. You can also try restarting Visual Studio.

Comment: @JamshaidKamran I have tried both your suggestions and the issue still persists.